# WHY? - completeMethod="#{testBean.itemList}": Method not found

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces

I need your collective expertise... *(thankyou for any guidance you can provide me!!)*

***Problem:***  My PrimeFaces "***p:autocomplete***" tag is generating a "***Method not found***" error on the "***completeMethod***" attribute...   --However, this method clearly appears to exist in the "***TestBean***" backing bean!

***Question:***  What is the cause of the error?
*(FWIW: Using this tag seemed to be a fairly intuitive task...at first.   --But, I am apparently fundamentally misunderstanding something...I just dont know what).*

***Here is the error message...***

```
WARNING: /index.xhtml @17,215 completeMethod="#{testBean.itemList}": Method not found: aaa.bbb.ccc.war.TestBean@13a494d.itemList(java.lang.String)
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @17,215 completeMethod="#{testBean.itemList}": Method not found: aaa.bbb.ccc.war.TestBean@13a494d.itemList(java.lang.String)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.broadcast(AutoComplete.java:358)
```

**here is the facelet page containing the p:autocomplete tag...**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/util"      
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">      
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>testprimeac</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="form1">
                <p:autoComplete id="abc"  dropdown="true" value="#{testBean.item}" completeMethod="#{testBean.itemList}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.itemLabel}" itemValue="#{item.itemValue}" forceSelection="true"></p:autoComplete>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**Here is the "TestBean" backing bean that contains the method in question *(or so I thought)*...**

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("testBean")
@Scope("request")
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
    public TestBean()
    {
    }

    private static final Map<String, String> listBoxEntryMap;
    static
    {
        Map<String, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        m.put("aaavalue", "aaalabel");
        m.put("bbbvalue", "aablabel");
        m.put("cccvalue", "abblabel");
        m.put("dddvalue", "bbblabel");
        m.put("eeevalue", "bbclabel");
        m.put("fffvalue", "bcclabel");
        m.put("gggvalue", "ccclabel");
        m.put("hhhvalue", "ccalabel");
        m.put("iiivalue", "caalabel");
        m.put("jjjvalue", "aaclabel");
        m.put("kkkvalue", "acclabel");
        m.put("lllvalue", "bbalabel");
        m.put("mmmvalue", "baalabel");

        listBoxEntryMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
    }

    private Item item;
    public Item getItem()
    {
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item i)
    {
        this.item = i;
    }    

    private static List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public void setItemList(List<Item> data) throws IOException
    {
        itemList = (null==data?new ArrayList<Item>():data);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("itemList",itemList);   
    }
    public static List<Item> getItemList()
    {
        if (null==itemList)
        {
            try
            {
                if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().containsKey("itemList"))
                {
                    itemList = (List<Item>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("itemList");            
                }

                if (null == itemList || itemList.isEmpty())
                {
                    itemList = getListOfItems();
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("itemList",itemList);            
                }

                return itemList; //(list);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        return itemList;
    }

    public static List<Item> getItemList(String s)
    {
        itemList = getItemList();
        List<Item> suggestions = new ArrayList<Item>();

        for (Item i : itemList)
        {
            if (i.getItemLabel().startsWith(s))
            {
                suggestions.add(i);
            }
        }

        return suggestions;
    }    


    public static List<Item> getListOfItems()
    {
        List<Item> list = null;
        try
        {
            Map<String, String> map = listBoxEntryMap;
            Iterator iter = map.keySet().iterator();

            list = new ArrayList<Item>();

            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                String key = (String) iter.next();
                String val = (String) map.get(key);
                list.add(new Item(key,val));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception during query call..." + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (null==list?new ArrayList<Item>():list);
    }
}
```

**Here is the "Item" pojo class used with the autocomplete *(value and label are both strings, which I think means that a "converter" class is not required)**

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
    }
    public Item(String l, String v)
    {
        this.itemLabel = (null == l ? "" : l);
        this.itemValue = (null == v ? "" : v);
    }
    private String itemLabel = "";
    private String itemValue = "";
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return (null == this.itemValue ? "" : this.itemValue);
    }
    public String getString()
    {
        return (null == this.itemValue ? "" : this.itemValue);
    }
    public String getItemLabel()
    {
        return (null == this.itemLabel ? "" : this.itemLabel);
    }
    public void setItemLabel(String s)
    {
        this.itemLabel = s;
    }
    public String getItemValue()
    {
        return (null == this.itemValue ? "" : this.itemValue);
    }
    public void setItemValue(String s)
    {
        this.itemValue = s;
    }
}
```

**FWIW - here is the build pom.xml, to view dependencies/versions used...**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprimeac-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>testprimeac-war</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <jsf-version>2.1.11</jsf-version>
    </properties>    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>testprimeac-${project.version}</finalName>       
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that you could narrow this down further, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completeMethod must evaluate to a MethodExpression.

See vdl [docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/autoComplete.html)

So change it to itemList() instead of a getter.

More info:

- https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExpressionLanguageFAQ

Comment: this solution is not working for me. If I add the () I get "Method not found: com.package.MyBean@5b4f1255.autoCompletarUbicacion()"
If I remove the () I get "Method not found: com.package.MyBean@5b4f1255.autoCompletarUbicacion(java.lang.String)". Any ideas? I'm using primefaces 4.0, myfaces 2.1.14

Comment: Hi Damian, what is the method name in your bean?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
private static List<Item> itemList;
 public TestBean(){
    itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
 }
```